# When I scroll horizontally through my collection view, the whole view reloads starting the animation again

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, collectionview

When I move the collection view across the screen, the whole view controller reloads again. This means that all the animations which occurred previously has to happen again. Is there a way to stop the view controller reloading when the collection view loads?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell2 = CollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookingDateCollectionCellClass

    let later = getDate(indexPath.row + 5).day
    print(later)


    let date: String = String(later)
    print(date)
    cell2.dateLabel.text = date

    let day = getDateData(indexPath.row + 5).dayOfWeek()
    print(day)
    cell2.dayLabel.text = dayShortFromNumber(day!)


    return cell2

}
```

[image: Before Start Animation]
[image: After Start Animation]

```
import UIKit

class BookingDateVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

// Outlets

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewDates: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var CollectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var bigMonthView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var selectDateLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var todayDateView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var todayButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var tomorrowButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var laterButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var monthView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!


// Calendar Variables
var month: Int?
var index: NSIndexPath?
var passData: dataReceipt?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Table View Customerisation
    tableViewDates.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 38/255, green: 163/255, blue: 133/255, alpha: 1)
    self.tableViewDates.center.y += self.view.bounds.height

}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // Sets up inital dates - Today, Tomorrow, Later
    let today = getDate(0).day
    let tomorrow = getDate(1).day
    let later = getDate(2).day

    todayButton.setTitle(String(today), forState: .Normal)
    tomorrowButton.setTitle(String(tomorrow), forState: .Normal)
    laterButton.setTitle(String(later), forState: .Normal)
    plusButton.setTitle("+", forState: .Normal)


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func todayButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    passData?.data = monthFromNumber(getDate(0).month) + " " + todayButton.currentTitle!
}

@IBAction func tomorrowButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    passData?.data = monthFromNumber(getDate(1).month) + " " + tomorrowButton.currentTitle!

}

// Gets date as components - Hour, Day, Month, Year
func getDate(days: Int) -> NSDateComponents{
    let date = getDateData(days)
    let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour, .Day, .Month, .Year]
    let components = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: date)
    return components

}

// Gets date + number of days from today
func getDateData(days: Int) -> NSDate{
    let today = NSDate()
    let date = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(
        .Day,
        value: days,
        toDate: today,
        options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))

    return date!
}

// Returns day string in full from day int
func dayFromNumber(day: Int) -> String{
    switch(day){
    case 1:
        return "SUNDAY"
    case 2:
        return "MONDAY"
    case 3:
        return "TUESDAY"
    case 4:
        return "WEDNESDAY"
    case 5:
        return "THURSDAY"
    case 6:
        return "FRIDAY"
    case 7:
        return "SATURDAY"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}

// Returns day string in short from day int
func dayShortFromNumber(day: Int) -> String{
    switch(day){
    case 1:
        return "SUN"
    case 2:
        return "MON"
    case 3:
        return "TUE"
    case 4:
        return "WED"
    case 5:
        return "THU"
    case 6:
        return "FRI"
    case 7:
        return "SAT"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}

// Returns month string in short from month int
func monthFromNumber(month: Int) -> String{
    switch(month){
    case 1:
        return "JAN"
    case 2:
        return "FEB"
    case 3:
        return "MAR"
    case 4:
        return "APR"
    case 5:
        return "MAY"
    case 6:
        return "JUN"
    case 7:
        return "JUL"
    case 8:
        return "AUG"
    case 9:
        return "SEP"
    case 10:
        return "OCT"
    case 11:
        return "NOV"
    case 12:
        return "DEC"
    default:
        return ""
    }
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewDates.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookingDateCellClass
    let later = getDate(2).day
    let date: String = String(indexPath.row + later)
    cell.dateLabel.text = date

    let day = getDateData(indexPath.row + 2).dayOfWeek()
    cell.dayLabel.text = dayFromNumber(day!)

    let bgColorView = UIView()
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 196/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView


    return cell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! BookingDateCellClass
    passData?.data =  monthFromNumber(getDate(indexPath.row + 2).month) + " " + cell.dateLabel.text!
    performSegueWithIdentifier("timeSegue", sender: self)
}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return false
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 60.0;//Choose your custom row height
}




@IBAction func laterButtonFunc(sender: AnyObject) {

    // Animates to later dates
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.tableViewDates.center.y = self.view.frame.height / 2

        self.todayDateView.center.y = self.view.frame.height / 6
        self.monthView.center.y = (self.view.frame.height / 4) * 3.25

    })
}


func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell2 = CollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BookingDateCollectionCellClass

    let later = getDate(indexPath.row + 5).day
    let date: String = String(later)
    cell2.dateLabel.text = date

    let day = getDateData(indexPath.row + 5).dayOfWeek()
    cell2.dayLabel.text = dayShortFromNumber(day!)
    //self.monthLabel.text = monthFromNumber(getDate(indexPath.row + 5).month)

    return cell2

    }
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! BookingDateCollectionCellClass
    passData?.data =  monthFromNumber(getDate(indexPath.row + 5).month) + " " + cell.dateLabel.text!
    performSegueWithIdentifier("timeSegue", sender: indexPath)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "timeSegue" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? BookingTimeVC {
            print((passData?.data)!)
            destination.passData = passData



        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: The view controller should not load when the collection view reloads. If it does, it's something you are doing in your code. You will need to provide a more detailed description of the sequence that triggers this reloading, including the code that's being called. I suggest you set a breakpoint in the method that's being called repeatedly, and look at the call stack to see how it's getting called again.

Comment: I've added full source code @DuncanC

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice that the dispatch isn't completely executing. You're touching the button before the thread completes executing. Further, I don't think the data is being called correctly. There should be seperate calls for setting the data *then* reload the table. Alternatively you could start setting the table data right when you segue so when the user gets to the VC everything is prepared. However, I'm leaning towards this being a dispatch issue.

Comment: It's just when the collection view is moved pasted the first index, after that it doesn't restart the screen @KFDoom

Comment: The collection view is moved past the first index of the tableview? I know it may seem like a stupid question but I like to clarify.

Comment: When you touch and drag the collection view (at the bottom of the screenshot), it restarts the page, but then it doesn't the second them you do it after it's reloaded @KFDoom

Comment: Yeah this is definitely* (hopefully) an app lifecycle problem. Editing answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115057/discussion-between-user-and-kfdoom).